# Appropriate font to show folder path

Tags: fonts

In a document I am writing I want to highlight somehow a folder path where the reader might find additional resources to reproduce the analysis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
The final dataset we used in our analysis, after the data munging process, 
was composed by 2498 observations and 14 variables
\footnote{Raw and processed datasets can be found in the ``/data/raw data/" and ``/data/processed data/" folders in the .zip file attached with this analysis.}.
\end{document}
```

Can you teach me the best practice when reporting folder paths? I mean the font/shape to use.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Package [url](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) has a `\path` command build in, setting the path in a monospaced font. Line breaks are also possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `url` (also loaded by `hyperref`) provides the command `\path` which seems to be useful here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}
The final dataset we used in our analysis, after the data munging process, 
was composed by 2498 observations and 14 variables
\footnote{Raw and processed datasets can be found in the \path{/data/raw data/ and /data/processed data/ folders} in the .zip file attached with this analysis.}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco! do you know how can I reproduce the white space between the words `raw` and `data`, and again between `processed` and `data`? the `\path` command seems to automatically delete them.

Comment: @Gianluca: Load `\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}` <-- new option ;-)

Comment: Thank you again Marco! An important thing to say is that the `obeyspaces` have to be called before the `url` package.

Answer (score 4):

You may like to have a look at my [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\directory}{pathswithfolder}

\begin{document}
The final dataset we used in our analysis, after the data munging process, 
was composed by 2498 observations and 14 variables
\footnote{Raw and processed datasets can be found in the
\directory{/data/raw data/and/data/processed data/folders}
in the .zip file attached with this analysis.}.
\end{document}
```

[image: menukeys directory formatting]